# Looping through large xml response then sending element back in another loop for response

Tags: php, xml, api

There has to be a better way! This is my code:

```
checksession();
$restNew2 = new RESTConnector();


$urlNew2 = "https://localhost:9630/api/products/";
$restNew2->createRequest($urlNew2,"GET", null, $_SESSION['cookies'][0]);
$restNew2->sendRequest();


$responseNew2 = $restNew2->getResponse();
$xmlNew2 = new SimpleXMLElement($responseNew2);

foreach ($xmlNew2 as $purge){
    $id = (string)$purge->attributes()->id;

checksession();
$restNew = new RESTConnector();


$urlNew = "https://localhost:9630/api/products/".$id."/";
$restNew->createRequest($urlNew2,"GET", null, $_SESSION['cookies'][0]);
$restNew->sendRequest();


$responseNew = $restNew->getResponse();
$xmlNew[] = new SimpleXMLElement($responseNew);



}
$array = array();

foreach ($xmlNew as $purgeDet){
    $code[] = (string)$purgeDet->code;
    $classId[] = (string)$purgeDet->class['id'];
    for($i=0, $count = count($xmlNew); $i < $count; $i++) {
$array[$code[$i]]['classId'] = $classId[$i];
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

The first response gives me about 300,000 lines back so then I have to parse through that to grab the id of a product in order to send another request to get a full render of the product. It ends up sending like 40,000 requests. My hopes is to insert this into a mySQL database at night using cron so I can create reports on it the next day. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You could store results in an array, then do a for each, but if you could cache data in a database it would be far better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id do it in chunks. Make the first API call and loop over it building a list of just ID's and store it. Id store them in a file with 1 per line... then you can the file line by line later instead of loading the whole array into buffer OR you coudl still read the file to an array... whichever ends up being the better solution.

Then read the file and loop through the IDs making your detail calls and storing them.

**UPDATE**:

You could also keep the grabbing of the IDs on the compiled side by using an xpath query.

```
$xmlNew2->xpath("//THE_ELEMENT_WITH_THE_ID/@id");
```

But i dunno if this is going to save you much because youd still need to loop over this... it just saves you have to call `SimpleXMLElement::attributes` on each node. But the result is still going to be array of attribute elements.

Comment: I get that not calling for the entire array saves memory but I still need to create 40,000 REST request to get each products details.

Comment: Well if the API doesnt let you grab more than one at a time then i dont think there is going to be any other way. You could just flag the item as requiring an update, and then not actually make the call for the full info until you run report and need the details from the item - then store the detail level data at that point.

Comment: Also there is no need to loop through the entire xml just use xpath to get what you need.. posting an update my answer...

Comment: xpath might be a little quicker even though I am getting most of the attributes. I will test and let you know. Thanks. Love your username btw.